# Drawing mesh currents in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz, circuits, engineering

My problem is that I don't know how to draw the circular-like shaped mesh currents in circuits. The following messy currents were generated with MS Paint. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[border=0.4cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages,cute inductors]
\draw 
  (0,3) to [V,l_=$\frac{1}{s}$](0,0)
  (4,3)
  node[label={above:$\text{V}_{x}$}] {}  
  to [R,*-*, l^=$1$] (4,0)
  node[label={below:Ref}] {}
  (8,3) to [V,l=$\frac{1}{s}$] (8,0)
  (0,0)--(8,0)
  (0,3) to [C,  l^=$\frac{2}{s}$] (4,3)
  to [L, l^=$4s$] (8,3)
;\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: meshcurrents]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw two `arc`s as in a normal tikzpicture.

```
\documentclass[border=0.4cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american voltages,cute inductors]
\draw 
  (0,3) to [V,l_=$\frac{1}{s}$](0,0)
  (4,3)
  node[label={above:$\text{V}_{x}$}] {}  
  to [R,*-*, l^=$1$] (4,0)
  node[label={below:Ref}] {}
  (8,3) to [V,l=$\frac{1}{s}$] (8,0)
  (0,0)--(8,0)
  (0,3) to [C,  l^=$\frac{2}{s}$] (4,3)
  to [L, l^=$4s$] (8,3);
  \draw[->,shift={(2,1.5)}] (120:.7cm) arc (120:-90:.7cm) node at(0,0){$I$};
  \draw[->,shift={(6,1.5)}] (120:.7cm) arc (120:-90:.7cm) node at(0,0){$I_L$};
  \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need. Just one thing: Can you show how to adjust the line thickness?

Comment: Just add the option `thick` or specify `line width=..`  in `\draw[thick,->,shift={(2,1.5)}]` and the other one.