# converting some handwritten network diagram into latex

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I wonder whether anyone knows how to draw the following in latex

[image]

I understand there is circuittikz but it does not quite match what is wanted here.
[circuittikz](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/circuitikz/)
Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Welcome, What did you try so far? where are your problems?

Comment: i use tex for over a decade but do not know the existence of a package does precisely describe the picture above

Comment: Hmmm... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467848/drawing-mesh-currents-in-circuitikz? (first hit for Google "circuitikz latex draw mesh current"...)

Comment: thanks @Rmano. I did try circuttikz package. Even I copy-paste the original codes from the link, it did not work...

Comment: Try to have a look at this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/524328/i-need-to-use-a-different-version-of-circuitikz-how-can-i-do-that . Otherwise, post your code in a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and I'll try to help.

Comment: i will do that later. I am on a ubuntu linux and I compile from terminal via pdflatex -shell-escape main.tex